# Symfony protect all directory by direct access

Tags: symfony

I have on a server a Symfony project with an API and my IP is configured for redirect to `/var/www` => index.html.

But in my browser, I can access whole project directory with this url for example : `http://MY_IP/MY_SF_PROJECT/`

What's the best way to protect my whole project for direct access ? I want to continue to access to my web folder but not the whole folder.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to add an index.html file to your folder to prevent folder listing.
Otherwise you should configure your webserver. For exemple, with Apache, you should set the Indexes option like this:

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options  -Indexes
</Directory>
```